# topological graph theory and the first Betti number

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am confused by a statement: in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number#Example_2:_the_first_Betti_number_in_graph_theory),

> In topological graph theory the first Betti number of a graph G with n vertices, m edges and k connected components equals $$m - n + k.$$

I am verifying two simple examples, **a disk** and **an annulus**. An annulus is the same as a cylinder.

> Ex 1: I suppose that a disk can be represented by a triangle (black region of the figure).
>   [image]
>   For a disk, we have
>   $$b_1=m - n + k=3-3+1=1.$$

**Question 1:** So is the first Betti number $b_1=1?$ Shouldn't a disk have the first Betti number $b_1=0?$

> Ex 2: I suppose that an anulus can be represented by a triangle with a hole triangle (black region of the figure).

[image]
For an annulus, we have
$$b_1=m - n + k=6-6+1=1.$$

**Question 2:** So is the first Betti number $b_1=1?$ This is the correct computation for an annulus--- the first Betti number $b_1=1?$ Correct?

Answer (score 3):

As is written in Wikipedia, the equality $b_1 = m - n + k$ makes sense and is true for topological [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), not arbitrary spaces. A full triangle and an annulus are not graphs, so the equality isn't true (the fact that you get the right result for the annulus is more of a coincidence than anything).

For an arbitrary CW complex, the [Euler characteristic $\chi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) is equal to the alternated sum of the number of cells in each dimension. For a topological graph, $\chi$ is equal to $b_0 - b_1$ where $b_0 = k$ is the number of connected components, hence the equality. As you can see this proof cannot work at all for arbitrary complexes.

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi: Very nice +1. Can you also show me the explicit 1st Betti number calculation of a disk and an annulus for using topological graphs?

Comment: OK, I understand the Euler characteristic argument. It is nice to use: $\chi=b_0-b_1 +\dots$.

Comment: But the explicit 1st Betti number calculation of a disk and an annulus for using topological graphs will be nice to confirm your answer.

Comment: These spaces aren't homeomorphic to graphs. They're homotopy equivalent to graphs though, respectively to a point and a circle. For the point you find $b_1 = 0 - 1 + 1 = 0$ and for the circle $b_1 = 1 - 1 + 1 = 1$.

Comment: I kind of agree my disk as a your point: b1=0−1+1=0 and my annulus as your circle: b1=n−n+1=1, like $n=3$ of a triangle.